# is $\langle\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n,g\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle u,g\rangle $ valid for bounded linear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose M is any linear manifold in H. H is a hilbert space. Define the orthogonal complement of M to be 
$$M' =\{f \in H | \langle f,g\rangle= 0 ,\forall g\in M\}.$$

To see that M' is a closed linear manifold, suppose $\{u_n\}$ is a sequence in
M', and that $\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=u$ is in $H$. For every $g\in M$ $$\langle u,g\rangle =\langle\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n,g\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle u,g\rangle =0.$$

The interchange of limits here is valid since (once again, by the Schwarz inequality) the linear operator $\langle u, g\rangle$ is a bounded linear operator for any fixed $g\in M$.

I dont understand the "interchange of limit**s**" Where is the second limit?

Answer (score 1):

It's just the English that is messing up with you. The plural is used like when you say "crossing street**s** without paying attention is dangerous"; where's the "second street"?

And *interchange* refers to exchanging the position of $\lim$ and $\langle$.

Comment: it says the **interchange** of limits? @Martin Argerami

Comment: Please see the edit.